# AttributeError: 'datetime.timezone' object has no attribute 'name' when trying to run Apache Airflow scheduler

Tags: python, airflow, pendulum

I have just setup a new Ubuntu machine, created a Python3.6 venv and installed airflow. I can start the webserver but when I try to run `airflow scheduler` I keep getting this error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/venv/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 398, in following_schedule
    tz = pendulum.timezone(self.timezone.name)
AttributeError: 'datetime.timezone' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is an excerpt of my `pip freeze`:

```
apache-airflow==1.10.5
boto3==1.9.253
Pillow==6.2.1
selenium==3.141.0
slackclient==1.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime.datetime` objects that you use have a `tzinfo` with no `name` attribute. For example if you use `datetime.timezone.utc` that implementation has no `name` attribute.

```
from datetime import datetime,timezone,timedelta
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="xxxx",
    default_args=args,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 5, 31, tzinfo=timezone.utc, # will raise AttributeError later
    schedule_interval="0 8 * * *",
    max_active_runs=1,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    catchup=False,
    description="xx",
)
```

So you need to provide another timezone object like the ones provided by pendulum package ( `tzinfo=pendulum.timezone("UTC")`).

```
import pendulum
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="xxxx",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 5, 31, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone("UTC"), 
    ...
    )
```

I submitted an issue to the airflow project to provide better error message for this particular case [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16551)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might simply need to use Airflow's special form of `datetime` objects (see the documentation and snippet [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/docs/timezone.rst#na%C3%AFve-and-aware-datetime-objects)).  If you replace all your current uses of `datetime.datetime` with invocations of `airflow.utils.timezone.datetime`, then the resulting objects will have `tzinfo`s with a `name` field.